# NSString encoding from strings with chars like \u00f6 to UTF8

Tags: cocoa

I get a NSStrings with characters like **\u00f6**. I can't find how to encode it to UTF8.

```
    NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:wikiSearchURL usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

Thanks...

Comment: Make sure not to use [stringWithContentsOfURL on the main thread](http://akosma.com/2010/05/28/initwithcontentsofurl-methods-considered-harmful/).

Comment: That line of code shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do this:

```
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:wikiSearchURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

the `usedEncoding:` one will tell you what encoding it used when it parsed the URL, while the `encoding:` one will force it to use a particular encoding.

Comment: `usedEncoding:` is probably correct unless you know for sure what the encoding of the resource at the URL is.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` conceptually uses UTF-16 as its inernal format.  `0x00F6` is a perfectly valid character to find in an `NSString`. It's o-umlaut.  If you want to convert the string to UTF-8, use `-UTF8String`

```
const char* foo = [myString UTF8String];
```

Note that your line of code which gets a string from a URL and tries to figure out which encoding was used is wrong.  You should use something like:

```
NSStringEncoding theEncoding;
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: wikiSearchURL usedEncoding: &theEncoding error:&err];
```

Assuming the returned string is not nil, `theEncoding` will now contain the encoding that was used to convert the URL content to the string.

Comment: Do you mean you have the sequence `Universit\u00e4t Leipzig` literally in your source code?  If so, try replacing the `\u` with `\x`.  `\u` is not a valid C language escape sequence.

Comment: My NSString contains "Universit\u00e4t Leipzig". That's what I got from [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:wikiSearchURL encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&err]. I want to replace all \udddd to UTF8 chars. "Universit\u00e4t Leipzig" => "Universität Leipzig"